# SELECT FOR UPDATE with INSERT INTO

Tags: mysql, select, insert, transactions, innodb

I have some kind of game lottery up in the making, and I've got advice to switch from MyISAM to the InnoDB and start using `FOR UPDATE` so a lottery ticket (ranging from 1 - 16) could not be sold more than once.

Now I'm wondering, how this `FOR UPDATE` is working.

I've seen on the web that it is something like :

```
SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE [column] = [value] FOR UPDATE
UPDATE [table] SET [column] = [new_value]
```

My question is however regarding the following, would it also work for an `INSERT`?

My database design:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Lottery` (
  `id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `preferedLotteryId` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `winningTicketId` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1',
  `createdOn` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '1001-00-00 00:00:00',
  `startedOn` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '1001-00-00 00:00:00',
  `finishedOn` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '1001-00-00 00:00:00',
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `deliveredOn` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '1001-00-00 00:00:00',
  `preferedDeliverMethod` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1',
  `deliveredMethod` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1',
  `deliveredByAccountId` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `LotteryBid` (
  `bidId` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `accountId` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `auctionId` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `ticketId` int(50) NOT NULL,
  `datetime` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '1001-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`bidId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Which means this design would require a `FOR UPDATE` similar to:

```
SELECT * FROM Lottery WHERE id = [id] FOR UPDATE
INSERT INTO LotteryBids SET [LotteryBids.values & Lottery.id]
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM Lottery WHERE id = [id] FOR UPDATE
INSERT INTO LotteryBids, Lottery SET [LotteryBids.values] WHERE Lottery.id = [id]
```

However, I have no idea whether this way of `FOR UPDATE` would be even slightly possible.

I'm pretty new to this massive data interaction, and I have no idea where to start.

I hope some of you guys could help me.

Kind Regards,
Larssy1

---

I assume that the following thoughts would translate to a possible solution:

Thought 1:

> A user is purchasing a lottery ticket with ticket id 5. Currently this
>   lottery has 3 tickets sold, so I want to lock the row count for this
>   lottery until I have committed/finished this insertion.

Thought 2:

> A user is purchasing a lottery ticket with ticket id 5. Currently this
>   auction has no ticket with ticket id 5, so i want to reserve an entry
>   for this auction with the similar auction id and ticket id. And
>   prevent further additions until this query has finished.

---

**Used queries**

Select a lottery (including additional information):

```
SELECT au.*, asp.* FROM Lottery au, LotteryPrefered asp
WHERE au.preferedAuctionId = asp.id AND au.id = '" . $_auctionId . "'
```

OR (excluding additional information)

```
SELECT au.* FROM Lottery au
WHERE au.id = '" . $_auctionId . "'
```

Purchase a ticket:

```
INSERT INTO LotteryBids (bidId, accountId, auctionId, ticketId, datetime)
VALUES ('" . $guid . "', '" . $_accountId . "', '" . $_auctionId . "',
  '" . $_ticketId . "', NOW())
```

Comment: I guess your `INSERT` statements are pseudocode, but what would the `WHERE` clause accomplish in the `INSERT` statement?

Comment: It's pretty much only for giving the little 'knock' to the `FOR UPDATE`, that an 'update' has occured. But I have no idea how it actually works.

Answer (score 21):

**SELECT ... FOR UPDATE with UPDATE**

Using transactions with InnoDB (auto-commit turned off), a `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` allows one session to temporarily lock down a particular record (or records) so that no other session can update it. Then, within the same transaction, the session can actually perform an `UPDATE` on the same record and commit or roll back the transaction. This would allow you to lock down the record so no other session could update it while perhaps you do some other business logic.

This is accomplished with locking. InnoDB utilizes indexes for locking records, so locking an existing record seems easy--simply lock the index for that record.

**SELECT ... FOR UPDATE with INSERT**

However, to use `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` with `INSERT`, how do you lock an index for a record that doesn't exist yet? If you are using the default isolation level of `REPEATABLE READ`, InnoDB will also utilize *gap* locks. As long as you know the `id` (or even range of ids) to lock, then InnoDB can lock the gap so no other record can be inserted in that gap until we're done with it.

If your `id` column were an auto-increment column, then `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` with `INSERT INTO` would be problematic because you wouldn't know what the new `id` was until you inserted it. However, since you know the `id` that you wish to insert, `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` with `INSERT` will work.

**Example**

See if `ticketid` `5` is available for auction `12`:

```
SELECT * FROM LotteryBids
WHERE auctionid = 12 AND ticketid = 5
FOR UPDATE
```

If no rows returned, then it doesn't exist. Insert it:

```
INSERT INTO LotteryBids (bidId, accountId, auctionId, ticketId, datetime)
VALUES ('abcd-efgh-ijkl-mnop', 100, 12, 5, NOW())
```

**Keep it simple**

Dealing with concurrency issues in such a manner can be difficult to understand, and I've often seen people overly complicate matters. I recommend asking a separate question detailing what you are trying to accomplish, provide your proposed solution, and ask for suggestions.

Comment: I see, thanks. The ID column is not an auto-increment because it's a varchar that holds a GUID which is created using a PHP class. If i'd give you the approriate data, could you create me an example of such `FOR UPDATE`? I know the website isn't primarely used for case-ready examples, 'let the community build your software'. But an example on which I could build forward on, would be highly appriciated. So again, if you are willing to, wwould test data be enough for you? -- question also updated

Comment: I don't yet understand what "purchasing a lottery ticket" entails. If you add the insert statements, I'll see if I can demonstrate the `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` statements.

Comment: @MarcusAdams Your answer is exactly right. I might add one additional note that the "gap" in this case *is locked* so be sure that's what you really want. You'll not be able to insert data with any other value in the entire range, which could be a large part of the table. For instance, in a table with 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, and you lock 10, it will actually lock the range from 5 -> supremum which means you can't lock any key >= 5. This is often seen with incrementing keys. With GUIDs/UUIDs you'd lock basically an arbitrarily large part of the table.

Comment: It's also worth noting that none of this works without using `START TRANSACTION` and `COMMIT` or setting `autocommit=0` for the session in question. (Since I notice that the asker didn't mention this.)

Comment: @MarcusAdams I'll add the queries in a moment to the starting topic.

Comment: @MarcusAdams queries added, if you're missing anything, please let me know.

Comment: @jeremycole would a lock in these queries prevent any changes, or only changes within a specific range? I would be awesome if i can set the range determined by a WHERE clause. Also, i've not seen those 'actions', so thats the reason i didn't include them. If you have any great advice, or tips how to get this working, please let me know. All feedback is recieved with open arms :)

Comment: I added an example to my answer. Simply specify the `ticketid` that you want to add in the `WHERE` clause. The range that actually gets locked depends on your data, but assuming max ticketid was 4, if your `WHERE` clause is `WHERE ticketid = 5`, the range `ticketid > 4` will be locked.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a kind of lock/MUTEX with an alternate table:
see http://blog.udby.com/archives/14 (Implementing simple database semaphore)

Before starting working on a given type, you lock the "type" with an INSERT + DELETE in the lock table.